# Selectize: Change searchField Dynamically

Tags: selectize.js

When using selectize I have a large group of users as my options, the field format for each option is:
{username, phone, dob}. I currently have my `searchField` set to be the username.

I was wondering if it is possible to change the `searchField` dynamically so that when I type only letters into the input that the `searchField` will be the 'username', but if I type only numbers, change the `searchField` to be 'phone'.

I have some code to do find out whether it is letters or numbers being entered, its the part after that I'm stuck on.

```
        selectize.on('type', function(str)
        {
            if (str.length > 3)
            {
                if (str.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, "").length == 0)
                {
                    // User is searching by phone
                }

                if (str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").length == 0)
                {
                    // User is searching by username
                }
            }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out in the end and thought I'd post the answer just in case anyone else is wondering.

You can set the 'searchField' option (as well as any other option I'm sure) by using:

```
selectize.settings.searchField = 'phone';
```